# Unset variable from php array

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I have an array which when printed out, looks something like below, although there are dozens of warning and success messages available:

```
Array
(
    [warning] => Array
        (
            [0] => We might have a problem.
            [1] => You might have a problem.
            [2] => They may have a problem.
        )

    [success] => Array
        (
            [0] => Everything is awesome
        )

)
```

I need to look in the array and find the warning with string value `You might have a problem.`. So I have the following code:

```
foreach($msgArray as $msgType => $messages) {
    foreach($messages as $message => $msg) {
        if($message == 'warning' && $msg == 'You might have a problem.'){
            unset($msgArray[$msgType]);
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately this removes *all* $msgType of `warning` from the `$msgArray`.

How can I remove *just* the warning with value "You might have a problem."?

Thanks!

Comment: you're really going to loop 2 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing the top level key. Just remove the second-level one instead:

```
unset($msgArray[$msgType][$message]);
```

P.S. Given the data and code you've shown, `$message` will *never* be `warning`. `$msgType` will be.

Comment: Thanks @Greg Schmidt - that was it. Incidentally, I was aiming to remove the $message where $msgType == warning, so your code was correct and mine was wrong all along!

Answer (score 0):

One line will do it without the loops and comparisons. Just search for the message to return the key and `unset` it:

```
unset($msgArray['warning'][array_search('You might have a problem.', $msgArray['warning'])]);
```